# Job listing website - Let my client adding new

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

I am a CS freshman from France and I am currently working on a very basic job-listing website with no login system (just applying directly on the job listing).

I have (almost)finished the front-end part using html, css and js but right now I am a bit confused on how I will be able to add and remove a job from the listing.

I currently hard code few jobs offers on my page (for design purposes) but it will be extremely time consuming to modify the source code by adding a new `<div>` whenever we have a new job available.

This is the current code structure for 1 job:

```
<div class="job job-1">
  <div class="job-title>
  Sales Assistant
  </div>
  <div class="job-location">
  London
  </div>
  <div class="job-date">
  2019/07/20
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user click on one of the job, a pop-up window appears and there is more information about the position following by the application form.

[job listing - desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srNfl.jpg)

Comment: You will need some sort of server-side code that interacts with a database. If your CS class assigned you this problem, you should've already covered some sort of server-side language in class.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have learnt Java, Python and C during my firs year. However, I never took any data base classes but I am aiming to learn on my own (like i have done for html, css and js). Do you think node.js and mySQL are optimal for this kind of project?

Comment: "Optimal" depends a lot on the class and the specifics of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment (yet), so sorry if i write here. You will need something to save the data. Easiest would be php+mysql imho.

Steps:

1) Create a html form, send data to the backend
2) create database and connect to it
2) Save data in the database
3) display data from database, replace your existing html with variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sascha. Would you rather chose PHP than Node.js? And thank you for the steeps, I have a better idea of what I have to do right now

Comment: i am not familar with Node, so personally i prefer php because i know it. php is beginner friendly. The best answar to this question can only come from a guy who masters both. I would go for php, just a couple of hours of work. You would require some login system as well, or you need to hide those content changing php scripts in a password protected directory.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with PHP. Modern PHP development looks nothing like the PHP 4 days most folks critical of it are basing their opinions in.

Comment: fully agree, i am mostly object orientated with class seperated, namespaces and auto loading of required classes. looks good, is maintainable and easy to handle. Plus you ll find most about php in the web.

Comment: B careful. As @SaschaGrindau said, PHP has come a long way. There's no denying that. Node is pretty fantastic, though. Don't base your decision here on a couple SO comments.